# After authentication it's not redirecting to next page in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I am not able to redirect to next page in Django after authentication.I have already defined next in views.py file and calling that value but in URL its redirecting to Login page with URL as below:

And without @login_required its working properly

After putting Username and Password  redirecting to

http://127.0.0.1:8000/?next=/home/

But I want:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/home ( And display Home page)

Please help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import auth
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
def login(request):
    next = request.POST.get('next', 'home/')
    if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


            if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                            auth.login(request, user)

                            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                    else:
                            return HttpResponse("Inactive user.")
            else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    return render(request, "login.html")

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)

@login_required(redirect_field_name='next')
def home(request):
    return render (request, "home.html")
```

App-urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url

 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
  ]
```

Project URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views


urlpatterns = [
         url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
         url(r'^home/', include('login.urls', namespace="login")),
         url(r'^$', views.login),
         url(r'^logout/$', views.logout),
 ]
```

Settings.py:

```
  import os

  # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  ...)
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See     https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(i34g@645+vc8$@y9qd)_fo1l#k%78up_cheab#!(b24xv$!uj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'login',
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  ]

 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
 ]

 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


 # Database
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}


 # Password validation
 # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-     validators

 AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
     {
    'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':  'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
 ]


 # Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

 USE_I18N = True

 USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


LOGIN_URL = 'login/'
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

Login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>

<section class="loginform cf">
<h1 style="color:blue"> User Login </h1>
<form name="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="{% url   'login:home' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="usermail" align="center">User-Id </label>
<input type="alphanumeric" name="userid" >
<br \>
<label for="password" align="center">Password </label>
<input type="alphanumeric" name="password" >
<br \>
<input type="submit" value="Login" style="color:blue">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
</center>
</form>
</section>
```

Comment: First and foremost, make sure you change your secret key since it's now available for all to see...

Answer (score 2):

You've got some different things going on that are affecting it.

Your `urls.py` file needs some cleaning up.  Because you've defined your own login/logout methods, you don't need to use the ones from `django.contrib.auth.views`.  So your base `urls.py` file should look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import login.views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', include('login.urls')
    url(r'^$', login.views.login)
    url(r'^logout/$', login.views.logout)
]
```

Your `login/urls.py` file can stay the same.  Now we are pointing login/logout to your views not the `django.contrib.auth.views`.

You have `settings.LOGIN_URL` set to `login/` but your `urls.py` file directs `/` to the login function.  For this answer, I'm changing `settings.LOGIN_URL` to `/` to match your url file.

Your `login/views.py` file only needed a few changes now that we've updated the `urls.py` file.

I cleaned up some of the import statements that were unnecessary and I removed `redirect_field_name='next'` from `@login_required` because `'next'` is the default value.

We need to check both the `POST` and `GET` objects to get the `next` parameter.

The biggest change is after we authenticate the user and validate that they're active, instead of `return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)` we just do `return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')` or send them to the `next` url that we grabbed from the `POST`/`GET` data.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings

def login(request):
    next = request.POST.get('next', request.GET.get('next', ''))
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if next:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Inactive user')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    return render(request, "login.html")

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    # Redirect back to login page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Once you have that, unless there's something else I'm missing, `@login_required` should properly redirect to your login page if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: Not sure I can help you without seeing your project.  What I answered works just fine for me when I create a new project.

Comment: I know you did.  As I said, it works for me in a new project.  So that tells me there's something incorrect or missing from your implementation.